# How to create an inherit model with more attributes than its parent in Ruby on Rails 4?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I need to create this structure in my database:
User
  |
  |_Admin
  |
  |_Moderator
  |
  |_Visitor

What I have done is to create the parent User in that way:

```
rails g model user name:string mail:string password:string description:string age:integer
```

And the children:

```
rails g model admin modules_to_admin:string --parent user
rails g model moderator days_to_moderate:string --parent user
rails g model visitor number_of_visits:integer --parent user
```

Rails created the three models and I'm able to create and Admin, Moderator or Visitor but they don't have their own attributes... and neither a migration is created so I don't know where is doing to be stored that data in my database.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You still need to generate migration scripts to add columns to User. Basically, Admin, Moderator, and Visitor are using their parent's table, "users" in this case.

If you want to have different tables, don't use this single-table inheritance but generate the models with their own tables. And, use good ole associations to link them up.

Comment: What I have done is to add their own attributes to User table, but only use in each case (each child) the attributes that I need. But, I want to associate Users between them so, I prefer to forget inheritance and create three different tables because is very difficult to do recursive links between "Users" and "Users"

Comment: Yeah. I would do that, if I were you.